# Is there an Official Ubuntu Server 16.04 vagrant box?

Tags: 16.04, server, virtualbox, vagrant

I can see Ubuntu 16.04, and Ubuntu Server 14.04, but there doesn't seem to be an official Server 16.04.

Does it exist somewhere else?

[Discover Vagrant Boxes | Vagrant Cloud](https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&sort=downloads&provider=&q=official%20ubuntu)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ubuntu/xenial64` appears to be the box you're looking for. Ubuntu always publishes under the ubuntu organization with the colloquial name of the OS and architecture.

Comment: @43Tesseracts Can you be more clear then? Xenial64 is their official server build for LTS.

Comment: I think I was confused by the lack of "Server" in the name of the box.  All the others say "Ubuntu Server" except this one.

Comment: isn't that the one with the screwed up password and the non-standard 'ubuntu' primary user account (instead of 'vagrant')?